# Question about using potential outcomes in DAGs in real world example

Tags: causality, graphical-model, treatment-effect, dag, counterfactuals

I am trying to understand how DAGs and potential outcomes look together.  I came across these excellent posts ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474616/strong-ignorability-confusion-on-the-relationship-between-outcomes-and-treatmen/474669#474669) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568411/difference-between-potential-outcome-and-outcome-conditioned-on-treatment?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I am trying to understand how this looks in a real world example.  There are not a lot of DAG examples in my field (International Relations), so I'll use a study on military experience and international conflict initiation as an example.

Study finds that ex-military leaders (T) are more likely to start conflicts (Y).  So the treatment is veteran leader, or rather the selection of a veteran leader.  Of course, the reasons for T=1 may be different than for T=0, so they control for a wide range of relevant confounders (C*).  However, these are all measured with some error and are essentially just proxies for C (international political factors).  Also, domestic politics (D) is probably an unobservable confounder that causes states to selects veterans and initiate conflict.  And there is also an unobservable mediator between X and T - the % of veterans in population (V).  So far, the true causal effect of T is unidentifiable, but thats expected given the nature of the data.  Not a problem since we are still interested in the effect of T, just removing as much bias as we possibly can by controlling for C*.

So here is the DAG I've got so far.  I think its right at this point.

[image]

The potential outcomes part is where I am having difficulty incorporating this into a DAG. For assignment of T, there are four potential outcomes:

1. Could have selected a veteran leader but did not (Pr[T = 1] > 0)
2. Could have selected a non-veteran leader but did not (Pr[T = 0] > 0)
3. Could never have selected a non-veteran leader (Pr[T = 1] = 0)
4. Could never have selected a veteran leader (Pr[T = 0] = 0)

For example, consider elections in State A and State B.  If say, 5/5 of the candidates were veterans in state A and 0/5 in state B, then obviously T=0 for State A and T=1 for state B could never have happened.  For the sake of argument, assume that D and V do not cause veterans to be more likely to be chosen over non-veterans where there is say, 3/5 candidates.  So what this means is that D and V affect whether treatment assignment is even possible, not necessarily treatment assignment. And if, say, State A were historically more conflict-prone, then this would entirely explain why veterans appeared more likely to initiate conflict.

So, if we were to only look at elections where T=1 or T=0 was even possible, is this perhaps the better way to reduce bias and close the backdoor paths from T to Y?  How does this look in a DAG?  Since selection is a common effect of D and V, it seems like this is somehow conditioning on a collider.  But theoretically it makes sense to me.

Comment: Are you able to find an instrumental variable? Or could you insert a variable in-between $T$ and $Y$ to set up the front-door formula? Conditioning on $C^*$ is not going to help much, I don't think.

Comment: Not a perfect one, no. Mostly because its hard to think of one that predicts T but is not somehow linked to a state's conflict behavior. None of the C* variables predict whether a veteran wins an election over non-veteran, only whether an election has at least one veteran candidate. So I was hoping that conditioning on elections where it is vet vs. non-vet would be the "best" method since it removes C altogether. Problem though, is that it seems like this is also conditioning on a collider. People could choose a veteran over non-veteran for a variety of reasons